# CSV upload to PySpark data frame counting linebreaks as new rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a CSV into a Spark data frame using common instructions, however, the CSV is incorrectly loading. Below is the header and a problematic record. This is the Vim view of the file, showing `^M` carriage return.

```
symbol,tweet_id,text,created_at,retweets,likes,geo,place,coordinates,location^M
AIG,1423790670557351945, "Next Monday, US stock market may edge up. The market is more likely to be mixed.
$MNST $AIG $WFC $GS $MET $BAC $JPM▒<80>▒",2021-08-06 23:38:43,1,0,,,,"Toronto, Ontario, Canada"^M
```

Here is the command I'm using to load the CSV into Spark data frame:

```
df = spark.read.load("symbols_tweets.csv",
                     format="csv", sep=",", header="true")
```

The issue is that `spark.read.load` ends up thinking `$MNST` is a new row since it appears on a new line. Is there any way I can have Spark pay attention to the Unix carriage return ^M instead so that it would load the rows as intended? As a workaround, I tried converting the CSV to Pandas data frame and then to Spark data frame, however that is resulting in more complex datatype issues - I would rather solve in a more direct manner.

Comment: also to note, Excel was able to read the format correctly -- also tried importing from XLS to spark, but also not working

Comment: got it working by adding multiline = "true" like this >>>>>>>   df = spark.read.load("symbols_tweets.csv",  format="csv", sep=",",header="true",multiline="true")